# Devise registration confirmation says that mail was sent but users don't see these messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I have Ruby on Rails application with devise authorization. I add confirmation for new user registration as in [manual](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users).

But new users doesn't receive confirmation messages.

Confirmation sending log says that email was successfully sent:

```
Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 262.0ms

Sent mail to new-user@email.com (60066.4ms)
Date: Tue, 27 Oct 2015 13:24:12 +0500
From: from@our-mail.com
Reply-To: reply-to@our-mail.com
To: from@our-mail.com
Message-ID: <message-id@my-machine.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hello new-user@email.com!</p>    
<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below.:</p>    
<p><a href="http://www.example.com:3100/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=token">Confirm my account</a></p>
```

But when I goes to new user's email, I don't see confirmation letter nowhere, even in spam folder. I tried several different email providers - everywhere result is same.

Another letters that I sends directly from my application code (without devise) sends and receives successfully.

My email sending settings in `/config/environment/development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'www.example.com:3100'}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => ENV['SMTP_ADDRESS'],
    :port => ENV['SMTP_PORT'],
    :user_name => ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
    :authentication => 'login',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

And `user` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable,
           :registerable,
           :confirmable,
           # :async, # I will enable async when confirmation will work at least in sync mode
           :recoverable,
           :rememberable,
           :trackable,
           :validatable,
           :omniauthable,
           :omniauth_providers => [:provider1, :provider2, ...]
```

What am I doing wrong? Where can I found reason of sending failure?

Comment: open /config/environment/development.rb and change      config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true to get the error for email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open /config/environment/development.rb

and change

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

to

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

to get the error for email.